# Rails ignores config/database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I uses Rails but it does not follow the settings in `config/database.yml`.

With `config/database.yml` (`$DATABASE_URL` is the URL of my Heroku app's database)

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  adapter: sqlite3
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I ran `rails g controller hoge`, then I got errors:

```
/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `load_dependency'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /myapp/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
    from /myapp/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise.rb:316:in `get'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise.rb:346:in `new'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise.rb:346:in `add_mapping'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
    from /myapp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `instance_exec'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `eval_block'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:418:in `draw'
    from /myapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from /myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

In Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'

  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'letter_opener_web'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'config'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'faraday_middleware'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'data-confirm-modal'
```

My ruby version is v2.5.0 and OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Why the adapter is set to `postgresql` in spite of `sqlite3` in `config/database.yml`?
How can I use the configurations correctly?

I think of migrating developing environment to virtual box (to avoid cumbersome problems like this), but I am afraid that, in the box, I would get such errors as well. Is it OK?

Comment: Sqlite is generally not used in production. You should either use Postgres locally or only use sqlite in the development group. Pretty sure you can't use sqlite on Heroku.

Comment: Yeah I can agree that there is no sqlite on heroku - pg only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is using the connection details from the environment variable, not the config file. Rails uses *both* `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and `config/database.yml` when setting up the database, and in most cases the environment variable has priority.

Take a look at [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) to see how the two ways of configuring the database interact.

The simplest solution in your case is probably to remove the `DATABASE_URL` varaible from your development machine. It’s unlikely you need it set there, and could possibly cause problems if you accidentally connect to the production database from development.

You could also use the `url:` key rather than the `database:` key when specifying the development database, as that key does take precedence over the environment variable. It would look something like:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  url: sqlite:db/development.sqlite3
```

You should also probably remove the `adapter` from `defaults`, as you are not using sqlite in production but are merging in that key. What you have will likely work (since the environment variable overrides the setting in the file), but it is confusing. Ideally you would want to look into using the same database in development and production to minimise differences between the two environments.

Comment: Thanks for much advise! It's fine.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem as well. How annoying...